# Visual Basic's On Error Resume Next for c++?

Tags: c++, vba, visual-c++, vb6

Is there an equivalent to Visual Basic‘s **On Error Resume Next** for C++ where by if an error occurs code continues to execute without prompting  user?

Ideally, would like to catch any exceptions and log them to log.txt file and examined later instead of having exceptions abruptly exiting code.

**Visual Basic:**

```
For i = 1 to 100
  On Error Resume Next
  ReturnedOpcVal[i] = OPC.ReadTag(“Server.Path.Tag” & "TagName_" & Cstr(i))
Next i
```

**C++**, I’m thinking this:

```
Try {
    // Try looping through code here
       For (i = 1;  i <= 100; i++)

           {
               // Read OPC tags code here
           }
    }

Catch(…)
   {
        // log error to file code
   }
```

Comment: Short answer is yes, exactly that: [exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/).

Comment: @Adriano - no you are incorrect, if an error is generated in the C++ code the loop will not continue to run, in the VB code it will.

Comment: @MattWilko I didn't say his code is correct or how he has to change it (that's why it's a comment instead of an answer), just that he has to use exceptions (with link to tutorial, letting him to see how they works and how to use them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the equivalent of the VB code:

```
   for (i = 1;  i <= 100; i++)
       {
           try {               
               // Read OPC tags code here
           catch(…)
           {

           }
       }
   }
```

but you may want to wrap another try catch block round the whole lot as well.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing like that. You'd have to write your code to catch and swallow the exception. Something like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++)
{
  try
  {
    // Read OPC tags code here
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    // Log something
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this different (what's bonus of) from what OP wrote itself as example?

Comment: @Adriano - In the VB6 code he posted the loop would run 100 times even if an error occurred. In the C++ code he posted the loop would exit when an exception was thrown, so not running 100 times.